# How to access Content-Disposition header in HttpClient response

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers, httpresponse

I want to download a file from a server and save it with the filename suggested by the server (using Content-Disposition header).

I am using HttpClient to download the file.

The problem is that I cannot get the value of the header, although `.Contains("Content-Disposition")` confirms that it exists. And there is no error, just the `.ContentDisposition` is null.

```
        public async Task DownloadFile(Uri url, string destination) {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", APIKey);
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent) {
                    return;
                }
                if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                    throw new Exception("Request from " + url + " returned " + result.StatusCode);
                }

                if (!result.Content.Headers.Contains("Content-Disposition")) {
                    throw new Exception("Request from " + url + " contains no content disposition header.");
                }
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue cd = result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition;
                if (cd == null) {
                    throw new Exception("Content disposition header is null. headers = " + result.Content.Headers);
                }

                var filename = cd.FileName;
                .
                .
                .
            }
        }
```

And the resulting exception is:
`Content disposition header is null. [...] Disposition: text/csv; filename=filename.csv [...]`

Why is the `.ContentDisposition` null, even though `.Contains("Content-Disposition")` is true?

Note that this is a Windows service, making debugging quite a bad experience.

Comment: You may want to read [You're Using HttpClient Wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx#:~:text=You%27re%20Using%20HttpClient%20Wrong%20There%27s%20a%20very%20good,call%20the%20object%27s%20Dispose%20method%20before%20discarding%20it%29.). It won't fix the problem in your question, but could prevent other issues from showing up.

Comment: If this is a CORS request, you could be forbidden from viewing the contents of the `Content-Disposition` header via the [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) header. Otherwise, try `result.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Disposition")`.

Comment: It's a regular client-server request, and the server response contains no Access-Control headers.

Thanks for the tip for reading, will definitely look at it.

> try `...GetValues(...)`
Yes, I will try. I don't like that it returns `IEnumerable` and I don't know how to work with it.

It just seems weird to me that I cannot get the result using its designated method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as @hereticmonkey suggested, I got the value using `result.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Disposition")`. That got me the string representation. When I tried to convert it to `ContentDispositionHeaderValue`, I got a `FormatException`. I have no idea why, as the header should be properly formatted, according to the relevant RFC: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1282661008.csv`. The exception itself won't explain much to me.

I had to parse it myself using regex:

```
if (!result.Content.Headers.Contains("Content-Disposition")) {
    throw new Exception("Request from " + url + " contains no content disposition header.");
}
string[] cdarray = result.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Disposition").ToArray();
if (cdarray.Length != 1) {
    throw new Exception("There is not exactly one Content-Disposition header. There is/are " + cdarray.Length);
}

GroupCollection groups = Regex.Match(cdarray[0], @"filename=""?([\w\.]*)""?").Groups;
if (groups.Count != 2) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to parse the Content-Disposition header " + cdarray[0]);
}
var filename = groups[1].Value;
```

I feel like there is something I don't get in .NET: Why there was no exception thrown when it failed to parse when accessing through `.ContentDisposition`? Why isn't the exception thrown while creating `ContentDispositionHeaderValue` more descriptive?

Comment: I see that using `new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("")` does NOT work, as it expects a `dispositionType` instead of the header value. But `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("attachment; filename=\"filename.jpg\"")` works. Except not in my case as the server returns an extra " in front (and only front..) of the filename. `ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("attachment; filename=\"filename.jpg")`